# How to prove a function continuous in its sorting variable?

Tags: functions, continuity

My apologies for the confusing title since it's hard to explain. Basically I have a function as following:

A list has 2 variables: $x$ and $y$. Sort the list by $x$. Then choose a value $x^*$ of x. The function $f(x^*)$ is defined as the sum in the $y$-dimension of all $x \geq x^*$.

That is, $f(x^*)=\sum(y)$ for all $y$ such that $x \geq x^*$. So when $x^*$ changes, the sum would potentially include more items.

For example, $x_1=1$, $y_1=2$, $x_2=2$, $y_2=1$, $x_3=3$, $y_3=4$, $x_4=4$, $y_4=2$.

Let $x^*=2$, then $f(x^*)=y_2+y_3+y_4=7$ since only $x_2, x_3, x_4$ have $x \geq x^*$.

If we let $x^*=3$, then $f(x^*)=y_3+y_4$.

I'm wondering how to show that $f(x^*)$ is continuous in $x^*$.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: This is still very, very confusing. I do not understand what $f$ is.

Comment: I edited the question. Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your own example, it certainly isn't.

We have that $f(x^*)=7$ if $2\leq x^*<3$ and $f(x^*)=6$ if $3\leq x^*<4$, so there's a discontinuity at $x^*=3$.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually trying to prove that the equation $x^*=f(x^*)$ has a solution by using fixed point theorem, hence trying to show continuity of $f(x^*)$. Is it possible to prove existence of solution for that one differently?

Comment: Are there any hypothesis on the values of $x,y$? Are they integers, positive? Or can they be any real numbers?

Comment: They can be any non-negative real numbers.

Comment: Then $f$ is non-increasing and right continuous. (I suppose the list is finite, right?)

Comment: Yes, the list is finite.

Comment: Sorry, $f$ is *left* continuous. I don't think such a fixed point will necessarily exist. Think about the graph of $g(x)=x$ and the graph of $f$. There is no particular reason for them to intersect. Indeed, consider the list with a single $x$-$y$ pair $\{(2,10)\}$. Then

$$
f(x^*)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
10,&x^*\leq2\\
0,&x^*>2\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and it's easy to see that no fixed point exists.